# How to Access iCloud from GAE

Tags: iphone, ios, google-app-engine, icloud

is there a way to access iCloud from a Google Web Engine App?

Tnx
Mica

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122123/can-developers-use-icloud-in-windows-apps